# Combine intersecting keys and values in 2 arrays

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I'm running through all of the array functions on php.net and unable to figure this out.

Essentially I want to take these two arrays:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [month] => October
        [year] => 2015
        [credit] => 1000.00
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [month] => September
        [year] => 2015
        [credit] => 200.00
    )
)

Array
(

[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [month] => October
        [year] => 2015
        [debit] => 2000.00
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [month] => August
        [year] => 2015
        [debit] => 50.00
    )
)
```

...and have the output look like this:

```
Array
(

[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [month] => October
        [year] => 2015
        [credit] => 1000.00
        [debit] => 2000.00
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [month] => September
        [year] => 2015
        [credit] => 200.00
        [debit] => 0
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [month] => August
        [year] => 2015
        [credit] => 0
        [debit] => 50.00
    )
)
```

I'm looked to merge "month" and "year" and combine the other keys, using a default value if the key doesn't exist.  Any guidance?

Comment: There isn't really a built-in PHP function for this, as far as I know, but you should be able to just iterate over both arrays and build a new array using month+year as keys. It should be pretty easy to combine them that way.

Comment: I would be interested to know how you would then access data from what you are calling the "desired" data structure.  To me, the data structure you propose would have limited usefulness in terms of allowing you to access the data inside of it.  It you were always going to output the entire array, then an array of objects might be OK, but if you then need to be able to do things like get information for specific years and/or months, this data structure would be very poor, requiring you to iterate the entire array every time you want to get at one specific piece of data within it.

Comment: @MikeBrant I agree with this as well. I am often unsure when answering whether to just show people how to do exactly what they're trying to do, or to propose something that seems better to me.

Comment: @Don'tPanic You should feel free to ask clarifying questions in comments.  I also think it is OK to answer the question as asked, but if you get an answer to your comment that may lead you to think another solution is appropriate, you can always edit your answer to show the alternate approach as well.  A future user arriving at the page can decide whether the question asked as it was makes sense for their needs, or whether the alternate approach that is identified might meet their needs.

Comment: @mike-brant I was working with both arrays separately which fed into a data table showing profits, but I now have a feature upgrade to add in date range filters, and I had a real issue handle 2 different arrays and comparing results and then cohesively showing the results as combined data.  I thought it best to get everything into one array where I can easily control the date ranges on the back end feeding into those arrays.  I believe my main issue is that both initial arrays come from the same table in the DB so joining is out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `$debits` and `$credits` are the arrays shown in your question, I would approach it like this:

First loop over the credits, inserting them into the new "combined" array and adding a default value for debit as you go.

```
foreach ($credits as $credit) {
    $credit->debit = 0.00;   // provide a default value for debit
    $combined[$credit->year . $credit->month] = $credit;
}
```

Then loop over the debits. Since there is the possibilities that entries will already be there from credits, there needs to be a check for this. This part should update existing values inserted from credits, or insert new values if there is no existing value.

```
foreach ($debits as $debit) {
    if (isset($combined[$debit->year . $debit->month])) {
        // update the debit if the entry already exists
        $combined[$debit->year . $debit->month]->debit = $debit->debit;
    } else {
        // otherwise create a new entry with a default value for credit
        $debit->credit = 0.00;
        $combined[$debit->year . $debit->month] = $debit;
    }
}

// If you need the results to be numerically indexed, you can use array_values
$numerically_indexed = array_values($combined);
```

Comment: Ahh!!  I was about 40% of the way there when I read your solution.  You literally nailed it.  Thank you Panic.

Comment: I added this at the end to handle profit addition:  <br/>
`// Create profit key and do the maths  <br/>
foreach ($combined as $value) {  <br/>
 $value->profit = $value->credit - $value->debit;  <br/>
 $value->profit = number_format($value->profit, 2, '.', '');  <br/>
 //print "<pre>";print_r($combined);exit();  <br/>
}`